# Python/PANDAS Date Correction in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime.date of 2016-12-27 or datetime.date(2016, 12, 27). This afflicts multiple dates, example: 2016-12-27, 2016-11-27.

How can I replace the 27 with just 01 without altering anything else? I have tried things such as:

```
df.DATE.replace(27, 01)
df.DATE.replace('-27', '-01')
df.DATE.replace(', 27', ', 01')
```

Pandas Version is 16.0
Python 2.7

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) attribute to filter on date and then `apply` a function to replace just the day component:

```
In [12]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2016,12,27), dt.datetime(2016,11,27), dt.datetime(2014, 5,3)]})
df
Out[12]:
        date
0 2016-12-27
1 2016-11-27
2 2014-05-03
In [14]:

df.loc[df.date.dt.day == 27, 'date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))
df
Out[14]:
        date
0 2016-12-01
1 2016-11-01
2 2014-05-03
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually just solved it myself by converting the column to a string, editing it, then converting it back to a date. I will accept this answer as it also seems to fit the need, without converting from string and back. Thanks!